# why am I getting setSessionTimeZone for nill:NillClass using activerecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oracle, activerecord

I have a user class setup like so:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

end
```

required active_record and the user class

```
require 'active_Record'
require 'features/support/database/ORMs/user'
```

connected to the database

```
ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
    :adapter => 'oracle_enhanced',
    :driver => 'oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver',
    :url => 'my_db_url'
    :username =>  'xxxxx',
    :password => 'yyyyy')
```

When I try to do User.first i get the following error

```
?> >> User.first
NoMethodError: undefined method `setSessionTimeZone' for nil:NilClass
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a rather cryptic error that indicates your database connection isn't set up properly.

If we look at [the source for the oracle_enhanced connection adapter](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/rsim/oracle-enhanced/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/OracleEnhancedJDBCConnection%3anew_connection), we can see that it tries to create a connection and then set the timezone:

```
@raw_connection = java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(url, properties)
@raw_connection.setSessionTimeZone(time_zone)
```

There's no error handling here (and there probably should be), so if `getConnection` returns `nil`, you'll get the *undefined method 'setSessionTimeZone' for nil:NilClass* error.

The solution will almost certainly lie in your configuration parameters, though without real values it's hard to spot any likely candidates.

Comment: I agree, however what doesn't make since is that the establish_connection call doesn't throw any errors

Comment: Was missing the JDBC leading string on the url